# Check if a folder is a package with Node

Tags: node.js, directory

I have a Node script that organizes files by putting them in folders with files' extensions as folder names, so all CSS files go into "css" folder, PSD go into "psd" folder, etc. It goes through all child subfolders as well, but I want to restrict it from going inside of the Mac OS package folders (the ones that have the option to "Show package contents" if you right click on it).

I cannot rely on the document type as those can be different: I've seen "Numbers" and "Application" so far. Any ideas?

Here is the function I'm using to loop through directories. Unfortunately, packages evaluate as true when I do `fs.statSync(name).isDirectory()`:

```
function getFiles(dir, files_) {
    files_ = files_ || [];
    var files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
    for (var i= 0, len = files.length; i<len; i++){
        var name = dir + '/' + files[i];
        if (fs.statSync(name).isDirectory()){ // AND NOT A PACKAGE
            getFiles(name, files_);
        } else {
            var extension = path.extname(name);

            // get rid of the dot and a space (if present)
            extension = extension.substring(1, extension.indexOf(' ') > -1 ? extension.indexOf(' ') : extension.length);

            sortFileByExtension(name,extension.toLowerCase());
            files_.push(name);
        }
    }
    return files_;
}
```

Comment: Have a look inside the folders, if there are files that distinguish a folder as a "package"; like a "hidden" file, or if the folder has a special name perhaps?

Comment: Not really. There is nothing special about the files inside.

Comment: You're saying the context menu shows differently for "package" folders, hence they have to have some kind of distinction. I may misunderstand, but, there is no "magic" about how something is recognized; it's all plain logic and clockwork; so there has to be some way of recognizing them accordingly.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what package gave a document type of "Numbers"?

Comment: This one: http://www.apple.com/mac/numbers/